# Syncing is slow from persistent Disk to Google Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcloud, rsync, bucket

We have around 11TB of images in local storage and the same has been copied to Google Cloud Bucket.  We have a requirement to sync all images incrementally i.e onlyn updated files.  Currently we are syncing files using below gsutil command.

gsutil -m rsync -r -C  /mnt/Test/ gs://test_images/test-H/

Issue which we are facing is it is taking around 6 days to copy and most of the time it is taking to scan the disk.  Please let me know if any method to copy updated data at least for 24hours.

Comment: What's your VM size? How many CPU?

Comment: In addition of @guillaumeblaquiere questions; Is your VM and your bucket in the same region? Which type of disk are you using?

Comment: 7GB Memory ,2 cores and Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS Operating System.

Comment: VM is in us-central1-a region and Multi region is enabled for bucket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To increase the transfer speed, here some tips:

- Use regional storage, the closest to your VM
- Use a VM with at least 8vCPU to maximise the bandwith like [described in quota](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/quota#per_instance)

> Depends on the machine type of the VM:
>
> All shared-core machine types are limited to 1 Gbps.
>
> 2 Gbps per vCPU, up to 32 Gbps per VM for machine types that use the Skylake or later CPU platforms with 16 or more vCPUs. This egress rate is also available for ultramem machine types.
>
> 2 Gbps per vCPU, up to 16 Gbps per VM for all other machine types with eight or more vCPUs.

Comment: If data copied by 2Gbps speed, then it should be completed in 13-14 hours, but now it is taking 4-5 days to complete.

Answer (score 0):

We have Increase the size of VM instance to N1-Standard-4 as it will provide more CPU power and network performance on the GCP network.  We noticed in stackdriver that the server was hitting 100% CPU utilization at times along with being limited to the max speeds allowed for GCP networking transfers due to the compute sizing and also we mounted bucket in the same server and executed the script.  Below is the command we used to mount and sync the files.

Below is the command used to authenticate google bucket.
gcloud auth application-default login

Mount disk by using below command.
gcsfuse --implicit-dirs Bucketname Mountpoint

sync the files using rsync command.

Comment: From Review: And what is exactly the proposed solution? Please edit your answer and add it, otherwise this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment.